# construct a python rich tree from list of descendants

Tags: python, tree, descendant, rich

I am trying to construct a python `rich.Tree` from a list of descendants, `d`.

```
d = {0: [1, 2], 2: [3, 4, 5], 4: [6, 7]}
```

I expect to get something like this:

```
# manually constructed string
expected = \
"""
0
├── 1
└── 2
    └── 3
    └── 4
        └── 6
        └── 7
    └── 5
"""
```

But I am getting confused as to how to proceed with the construction: the following code is not correct.

```
from rich.tree import Tree
from rich import print as rprint

tree = Tree("0")
tree.add("1")
tree.add("2").add("3")
tree.add("4").add("6").add("7")
tree.add("5")
rprint(tree)

0
├── 1
├── 2
│   └── 3
├── 4
│   └── 6
│       └── 7
└── 5
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive function to convert the dictionary representation of your tree (i.e. the adjacency list) to the nested tree object:

```
def make_tree(adj, node=0):
    tree = Tree(str(node))
    for child in adj.get(node, []):
        tree.add(make_tree(adj, child))
    return tree
```

Call like this:

```
d = {0: [1, 2], 2: [3, 4, 5], 4: [6, 7]}
tree = make_tree(d)
rprint(tree)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
from rich.tree import Tree
from rich import print as rprint

tree = Tree("0")
tree.add("1")
tree.add("2").add("3")
four_branch = tree.add("4")
four_branch.add("6")
four_branch.add("7")
tree.add("5")
rprint(tree)
```

If you look at [the example they linked to](https://github.com/Textualize/rich/blob/master/examples/tree.py#L29) in the documentation, you'll see that the `tree.add(...)` returns a value that you can then add to